# SAP Abap code not working | Field "CHECK_PRIME" is unknown. | The method "CHECK_PRIME" is not declared or inherited in class "ZCL_NTH_PRIME". |

Tags: frontend, primes, abap

```
REPORT Z_PRIMENUMBER.

CLASS ZCL_NTH_PRIME DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS prime
      IMPORTING
        input         TYPE i
      RETURNING
        VALUE(result) TYPE i
      RAISING
        cx_parameter_invalid.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ZCL_NTH_PRIME IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD prime.
    IF input = 0.
      RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_parameter_invalid.
    ENDIF.

    DATA prime_number TYPE i.
    DATA prime_count TYPE i.
    prime_number = 2.
    prime_count = 0.

    DO.
      IF check_prime(prime_number) = abap_true.
        prime_count = prime_count + 1.
      ENDIF.

      IF prime_count = input.
        result = prime_number.
        EXIT.
      ENDIF.

      prime_number = prime_number + 1.
    ENDDO.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD check_prime.
    DATA number TYPE i.
    DATA is_prime TYPE abap_bool.
    number = 2.
    is_prime = abap_true.

    DO number = 2 TO sqrt(input).
      IF input MOD number = 0.
        is_prime = abap_false.
        EXIT.
      ENDIF.
    ENDDO.

    result = is_prime.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

DATA: nth_prime TYPE i,
      result TYPE i.

nth_prime = 10.

DATA: prime_calculator TYPE REF TO ZCL_NTH_PRIME.

CREATE OBJECT prime_calculator.

TRY.
    prime_calculator->prime( nth_prime )->result.
    result = nth_prime.
    WRITE: / 'The', nth_prime, 'th prime number is', result.
CATCH cx_parameter_invalid INTO DATA(exception).
    WRITE: / 'Error:', exception->get_text( ).
ENDTRY.
```

It's showing errors:

"Field "CHECK_PRIME" is unknown" at this line: `IF check_prime(prime_number) = abap_true.`

"The method "CHECK_PRIME" is not declared or inherited in class "ZCL_NTH_PRIME" at this line: `METHOD check_prime`

I was expecting that this code will show me the prime numbers after nth number.
The errors at specific lines are not solving I am trying for 4 days and its still the same I have done everything maybe I have less experience but can someone suggest me to solve this error.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as "needs detail or clarity". It contains the sourcecode and the error message that happens when you activate it. That was all I needed to answer. What more "detail or clarity" do you expect, President James K. Polk, Zephyr and Sandra Rossi?

Answer (score 1):

The error message `The method "CHECK_PRIME" is not declared or inherited in class "ZCL_NTH_PRIME"` means exactly what is says. You are trying to implement and call a method you didn't declare between `CLASS ZCL_NTH_PRIME DEFINITION` and the corresponding `ENCLASS.`.

You have a method that is called `prime` in your class definition, but not a method called `check_prime`. So what you need to do is add the declaration for that second method. Guessing from context and from the undeclared variables you are using in the implementation of that method, I would say that it would have to look something like this:

```
METHODS check_prime
  IMPORTING
    input         TYPE i
  RETURNING
    VALUE(result) TYPE abap_bool.
```

Where exactly does that definition belong? Considering that the method doesn't seem to get called from outside the class, it doesn't need to be in the `PUBLIC SECTION`. Considering that the class is `FINAL`, there can't be any class that inherits from it. Which means that there is no point in putting anything into the `PROTECTED SECTION`. So you should probably put it into the `PRIVATE SECTION`.